# How do you determine if an insert or update was successful using wso2 ESB and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wso2-esb

I use wso2ESB 4.9. I want known after update in Mysql how many of records are update. I use below config:

```
              <dbreport>
                <connection>
                  <pool>
                    <dsName>jdbc/localdb</dsName>
                  </pool>
                </connection>
                <statement>
                  <sql><![CDATA[update table1 set active=0  where username=?  ]]></sql>
                  <parameter expression="get-property('username')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                </statement>
              </dbreport>
```

How to know that there is a record update or not ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. The simple one is just use a dblookup and retrieve 'row_count'; 
Another is to create a stored procedure or function call. An example would be:

```
delimiter //
create function setActive (name VARCHAR(50)) returns int DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
UPDATE table1 set active=0 where username=name;
RETURN ROW_COUNT();
END
//
delimiter ;
```

You could then use in the dblookup:

```
  <sql>SELECT setActive(?)</sql>
  <parameter expression="get-property('username')" type="VARCHAR"/>
  <result name="res" column="row_count()"/>
```